# What happened to `setFontType` command?

Tags: jspdf

I'm upgrading from 1.5.3. to 2.1.1, suddenly my code breaks because `setFontType` is no longer a thing... but there's nothing in the docs about this change that I can find.

So what do I do?

I have this:

```
this.doc = new jsPDF();
this.setFont("helvetica", "bolditalic");
```

... do some stuff ...
Then I want 'normal' instead of bold italic

```
this.doc.setFontType('normal');
```

... which gives error:

```
"TypeError: this.doc.setFontType is not a function"
```

Answer (score 13):

Looks like they updated the API.  Try

`doc.setFont(undefined, 'bold')`

and

`doc.setFont(undefined, 'normal')`

See: http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/jsPDF.html#setFont

Comment: It's weird that you have to set undefined for the fonts just to make existing fonts bold.