# setfontstyle is not a function issue,jspdf

Tags: angular, jspdf

**issue**
i'm using jspdf 2.5.1 and i'm facing the issue that says doc.setFontType is not a function.
and im using angular 12.

this is how i import jspdf

```
declare const require: any;
const { jsPDF } = require("jspdf");
require('jspdf-autotable');
```

i have tried importing jspdf this ways too and face many issues

```
import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf' // this doesnt work for me
import { jsPDF } from 'jspdf'; //this doesnt work for me
```

**code**
the issue is face in this section

```
downloadPDF(isSubmit:any) {        
    let doc = new jsPDF();
    let rows: Array<any> = [];
    let medicineInfo: any;
    let physicianInfo: any;
    doc.page = 1;

    var col = ["Medicine Name", "Dose", "Dispense"];
    this.prescriptionModel.prescriptionDetails.forEach((a) => {
      medicineInfo = this.masterDrugMedication.find(x => x.id == a.prescriptionId);
      rows.push(['' + a.productId + ' ' + a.strength + ', ' + a.route + '', '' + a.direction + '', '' + a.quantity + '']);
    });

    
    physicianInfo = this.masterStaff.find(x => x.id == this.prescriptionModel.physician);
    
    if (this.prescriptionModel.id > 0) {                 
        if (this.reportCommonData != null) {
          doc.setProperties({title: "Prescription Report"});  
          doc.setFontType("bold");
          doc.setFontSize(16);
          doc.text(15, 20, "Prescription Report");
          doc.setFontSize(10);
          ...
```

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64518601/what-happened-to-setfonttype-command) will help you.